# Compute $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{[x]}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

When I take left hand limit of the function $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{[x]}$, then $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{-h}{[-h]}=\lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{-h}{-1}=0$ where $0<h<1$ and $[\cdot ]$ is greatest integer function. But when I take right hand limit, then the function $\frac{h}{[h]}$ does not exists. so I do not understand what about $\lim\limits_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{h}{[h]}$ and the limit of original function. Does the limit exists? please someone help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you divide by $0$ ??

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: The limit is not even defined. In order to discuss the limit of a function $f$ at a point $p$ one implicitly assumes that there is a number $r>0$ such that the function is defined on the interval $(p-r,p+r)$ except possibly at $p$ itself.

Comment: Why the downvote? The question clearly shows OP's effort to understand it.

Comment: I think you understand the math and your question is more about examsmanship (= what did the person who posed the question want as an answer?) or about conventions for talking about infinities.  The limit of $x/\lfloor x \rfloor$ from the right is either $+\infty$ (because $x/\lfloor x \rfloor$ is itself $+\infty$ for $0<x<1$) or else undefined, depending on your conventions -- people sometimes use $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ when talking about limits, for example Baby Rudin 3.15.

Comment: Here the left hand limit is 0 but for the right hand limit the function itself does not exists. I think  its right hand limit is trivially 0. But I am not confident on it.

Comment: It depends on conventions; if “$x$ in the domain of the function” is implied, then the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There  is a   theorem in Analysis which states:

> Given a limit point $c$  of   a set   $A$    and  a  function      $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,  $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=L$     if and only if 
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{x\rightarrow c^-}f(x)=L\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{x\rightarrow c^+}f(x)=L
> \end{align*}

Since in our example the right-hand limit $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{x}{[x]}$  does not exist it follows, that the limit  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{[x]}$$ does not exist.

Comment: I've tried to edit my question a little to be more clear. Is the function exists when we take $x$ from the right hand side of $0$? Then we take right hand limit of the function. Ok thank you for your help.

Comment: @user292213: You're welcome.